# openssl and pluggable engine digests

Tags: openssl

So, in LibreSSL, say, I have a call like

```
openssl req -newkey gost2001 -pkeyopt dgst:streebog256 -pkeyopt paramset:A -streebog256 \
-nodes -subj "/C=Some/ST=Some/O=FooBar LLC/CN=John Doe/emailaddress=doe@foo.bar" \
-keyout /tmp/key.pem -out /tmp/csr.pem -utf8
```

and it pretty much does the job. But in OpenSSL 3.0 I have gost as a pluggable engine, and it doesn't recognize the streebog256 as the acceptable digest:

```
Key parameter error "dgst:streebog256"
```

That is because it's manual page clearly states:

> "The engine is not used for digests unless the -engine_impl option is used or it is configured to do so, see "Engine Configuration Module" in config(5)."

Funny thing is, the config(5) manual page doesnt'y say a word about configuring digests (I was able to configure gost as an engine for default loading as there are plenty of examples).

So, when using `openssl dgst` with both `-engine gost` and `-engine_impl gost` I can see the needed *streebog256* as valid digest but how do I do this while calling `openssl req` or when using `openssl.cnf` ?

Answer (score 0):

In OpenSSL 3.0, you can configure the engine to use the streebog256 digest for the `openssl req` command by adding the following line to your openssl.cnf file:

```
openssl_conf = openssl_init

[openssl_init]
engines = engine_section

[engine_section]
gost = gost_section

[gost_section]
default_algorithms = ALL,dgst,streebog256
```

This will set the streebog256 digest as the default digest for the GOST engine. Then you can use the following command to generate your CSR:

```
openssl req -newkey gost2001 -pkeyopt dgst:gost -pkeyopt paramset:A -streebog256 \
-nodes -subj "/C=Some/ST=Some/O=FooBar LLC/CN=John Doe/emailaddress=doe@foo.bar" \
-keyout /tmp/key.pem -out /tmp/csr.pem -utf8 -engine gost
```